# What should i do with sorted array searching?

Tags: java

```
public class searchinsertdeletesort {
static void search(int a[],int n,int e){
    int beg=0,end=n-1;
    int mid;
    while(beg<=end)
    {
        mid=(end-beg)/2;
        if(a[mid]==e)
        {
            System.out.println("Success");
            return;
        }
        else if(e<a[mid])
        {
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else if(e>a[mid])
        {
            beg=mid+1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Failes");
    return;
}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5},i,e,in,j;
    int n=a.length;
    //search
    System.out.println("Search:");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    e=s.nextInt();
    search(a,n,e);
    //insert
    in=s.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>in)
        {
            for(j=n;j>i;j--)
            {
                a[j]=a[j-1];
            }
            a[i]=in;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }

}
```

}

this when i run and input any number for my array keeps asking me to input number . it doesn't show anything else . All i can do is input number
For example it askes for searching : 
i input 2
then i can input again idk why
then i keep inputting but nothing happens

Comment: Please **clearly describe** the problem. Explain what your code is supposed to do. Show some example input, the desired output and the current output, demonstrate the problem. If you implemented a specific search algorithm, please add the corresponding tag, then experts on this algorithm will be able to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with taking the `mid`. It should be `mid=(end+beg)/2;` because
`(end-beg)/2` won't give the exact index of the mid. ex: if `beg=5` and `end=9`, `(end-beg)/2` will give `2` which is incorrect, whereas `(end+beg)/2` gives `7`.